How can I use an npm package with TypeScript code encapsulated in namespaces?
I am trying to use an npm package that has interfaces encapsulated in namespaces.
I have installed the npm package using:
npm install xserver-code
It has downloaded the following file:
node_modules/xserver-code/dist/application/xserver-interface.d.ts
With the contents:
declare namespace Xserver.Application {
    interface XServerInterface {
        serve(): void;
    }
}

I want to use the XServerInterface in my TypesSript project to define a class, how can I?
I would usually do:
import { XServerInterface } from 'xserver-code';
But this is not working, I get the error:
Cannot find module 'xserver-code' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
What am I doing wrong?

To use an npm package with TypeScript code encapsulated in namespaces, you need to ensure that the TypeScript compiler is aware of the type declarations. In your case, the xserver-code package uses namespaces rather than ES modules, which requires a different approach to importing and using these types in your TypeScript project.
Here are the steps to correctly use the XServerInterface from the xserver-code package:

Install the npm package:
You already installed the package using:
npm install xserver-code


Include TypeScript declaration files:
Ensure that the TypeScript compiler includes the declaration files from xserver-code. You can do this by either referencing the declaration file directly in your TypeScript file or by adding a reference to the types in your tsconfig.json.

Reference the namespace directly:
Since the xserver-code package uses namespaces, you don’t need to use the import statement. Instead, you directly use the namespace provided by the package.


Here’s how you can do it:
Direct Reference in TypeScript File
If you want to use the interface directly in a TypeScript file, you can add a reference to the declaration file at the top of your file:
/// <reference path="../node_modules/xserver-code/dist/application/xserver-interface.d.ts" />

class MyServer implements Xserver.Application.XServerInterface {
    serve(): void {
        console.log("Serving...");
    }
}

const server = new MyServer();
server.serve();

Adding Types to tsconfig.json
You can also configure your tsconfig.json to include the type declarations globally:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "node_modules/xserver-code/dist/application"],
    "types": ["xserver-code"]
  }
}

Using the Namespace
With the namespace properly referenced, you can define your class implementing the interface:
class MyServer implements Xserver.Application.XServerInterface {
    serve(): void {
        console.log("Serving...");
    }
}

const server = new MyServer();
server.serve();

Alternative: Create a TypeScript Declaration File
Alternatively, you can create a local declaration file (e.g., xserver-code.d.ts) in your project with the necessary declarations:
declare namespace Xserver.Application {
    interface XServerInterface {
        serve(): void;
    }
}

Then include this file in your tsconfig.json:
{
  "include": ["src", "xserver-code.d.ts"]
}

And then you can use it as shown earlier:
class MyServer implements Xserver.Application.XServerInterface {
    serve(): void {
        console.log("Serving...");
    }
}

const server = new MyServer();
server.serve();

By following these steps, you should be able to use the XServerInterface from the xserver-code package in your TypeScript project without encountering module resolution issues.

is there any way I can use reference  to bring in all the files in the npm package, as it has a lot of classes and methods?
